# What are .git/info/grafts for?

Tags: git, version-control

I am trying to figure out what is the 'grafts' in the Git.

For example, in one of the latest comments [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20080930112610/http://log.emmanuelebassi.net/archives/2007/09/when-the-levee-breaks/), Tobu suppose to use **git-filter-branch** and **.git/info/grafts** to join two repositories.

But I don't understand why I need these *grafts*? It seems, that all work without last two commands.

Comment: The link 'here' has disappeared but is copied at http://www.seattlecentral.edu/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/dmartin/moin.cgi/Git

Comment: Warning: grafts have been removed in Git 2.18 (Q2 2018). See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50517809/6309)

Answer (score 39):

From [Git Wiki](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GraftPoint):

> Graft points or grafts enable two
>   otherwise different lines of
>   development to be joined together. It
>   works by letting users record fake
>   ancestry information for commits. This
>   way you can make git pretend the set
>   of parents a commit has is different
>   from what was recorded when the commit
>   was created.
>
> **Reasons for Using Grafts**
>
> Grafts can be useful when moving
>   development to git, since it allows
>   you to make cloning of the old history
>   imported from another SCM optional.
>   This keeps the initial clone for users
>   who just wants to follow the latest
>   version down while developers can have
>   the full development history
>   available.
>
> When Linus started using git for
>   maintaining his kernel tree there
>   didn't exist any tools to convert the
>   old kernel history. Later, when the
>   old kernel history was imported into
>   git from the bkcvs gateway, grafts was
>   created as a method for making it
>   possible to tie the two different
>   repositories together.

Answer (score 15):

The grafts approach [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3148117/6309) by [Chris Johnsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/193688/chris-johnsen) for joining two repositories is no longer *fully* valid (with grafts alone).
With Git 2.18 (Q2 2018), the functionality of "`$GIT_DIR/info/grafts`" has been superseded by the "`refs/replace/`" mechanism (for some time now).
The internal code had support for it in many places, which has been cleaned up
**in order to drop support of the "grafts" mechanism**.

See [commit a3694d9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a3694d949fcd39f9a909cf762f698df8ce83215c), [commit f42fa47](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f42fa470b0d87fcb36475f78f2366bba6864895a), [commit 8d0d81a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d0d81a9caf612b479b96bc474815e2f38c4746b), [commit e2d65c1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e2d65c1ea810f34681c3f3aba03c58b6e8484b3f), [commit f9f99b3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f9f99b3f7d06716336b239bcf122eb5a7348bfd5), [commit 0115e03](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0115e030db499853a77c2b92dc8c6a51552009ef), [commit fb40429](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fb40429109723c0d8ec77ba81421f508ac2532a0), [commit 041c98e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/041c98e22d88d963a92f1bac6ab348a0d4c6d228), [commit e24e871](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e24e871920ac04473a470645e4c4dc53b422dd75) (28 Apr 2018), and [commit d398f2e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d398f2ea001ab4e639896c81fb616810cf14eb12), [commit fef461e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fef461ea5d53dd84c6d946f57a018ffc9f391a05), [commit c5aa6db](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c5aa6db64f6f43621568bb1fec9360c25dbd2749) (25 Apr 2018) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 352cf6c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/352cf6cfe138b1dbcf9c105c91ca793b67511d7b), 23 May 2018)</sup>

So instead of

```
echo "$commit-id $graft-id" >> .git/info/grafts
```

You now do:

```
git replace --graft $commit-id $graft-id
git filter-branch $graft-id..HEAD
```

> ### Deprecate support for `.git/info/grafts`
>
> The grafts feature was a convenient way to "stitch together" ancient
>   history to the fresh start of `linux.git`.
>
> Its implementation is, however, not up to Git's standards, as there are
>   too many ways where it can lead to surprising and unwelcome behavior.
>
> For example, when pushing from a repository with active grafts, it is
>   possible to miss commits that have been "grafted out", resulting in a
>   broken state on the other side.
>
> Also, the grafts feature is limited to "rewriting" commits' list of
>   parents, it cannot replace anything else.
>
> The much younger feature implemented as `git replace` set out to remedy
>   those limitations and dangerous bugs.
>
> Seeing as `git replace` is pretty mature by now (since [4228e8b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4228e8bc989c6cac1c47faece720faa06531281f)
>   (replace: add `--graft` option, 2014-07-19, Git 2.1.0) it can perform the graft
>   file's duties), it is time to deprecate support for the graft file, and
>   to retire it eventually.

Now (again, Git 2.18, Q2 2018), you have:

> ### `replace`: add `--graft` option
>
> The usage string for this option is:
>
> ```
> git replace [-f] --graft <commit> [<parent>...]
> ```
>
> First we create a new commit that is the same as `<commit>`
>   except that its parents are `[<parents>...]`
>
> Then we create a replace ref that replace  with
>   the commit we just created.
>
> With this new option, it should be straightforward to
>   convert grafts to replace refs.

---

And before Git 2.20 (Q4 2018), the recently introduced commit-graph auxiliary data is incompatible with mechanisms such as replace & grafts that "breaks" immutable nature of the object reference relationship.
**Disable optimizations based on its use (and updating existing commit-graph) when these incompatible features are in use in the repository.**

See [commit 829a321](https://github.com/git/git/commit/829a321569d8e8f2c582aef9f0c990df976ab842), [commit 5cef295](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5cef295f283e84351a104c66f949a53a56297aa7), [commit 20fd6d5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/20fd6d57996e33c30b6bb030329523d0116f15ec), [commit d653824](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d6538246d3d4edbfbc9b0af6a2aa38552d35f7f1), [commit b775896](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b7758963424e238b9152f0c9991325ff7fdffff1), [commit 950c62b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/950c62bda208790e223230a73ce6c19ae8f9177b) (20 Aug 2018) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
See [commit 212e0f7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/212e0f7efe163d062dcd393a0788cf3f93544a6e), [commit 4a6067c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a6067cda51b592871144eb050d4673db9ad5103) (20 Aug 2018) by [Stefan Beller (`stefanbeller`)](https://github.com/stefanbeller).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6d8f8eb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6d8f8ebb74d21b51cfbf427a436094134af36ee2), 16 Oct 2018)</sup>

---

With Git 2.24 (Q4 2019), the "`upload-pack`" (the counterpart of "`git fetch`"), which needs to disable commit-graph when responding to a shallow clone/fetch request, does not panic anymore.

See [commit 6abada1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6abada1880156df9c6a0de91fb23716e378e13d7), [commit fbab552](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fbab552a53a2558ec84a06034e6657fb95227266) (12 Sep 2019) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 098e8c6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/098e8c6716b8c6abc29b6788acdb3ac8725f835d), 07 Oct 2019)</sup>

> ## `upload-pack`: disable commit graph more gently for shallow traversal
>
> When the client has asked for certain shallow options like "deepen-since", we do a custom rev-list walk that pretends to be shallow.
>   Before doing so, we have to disable the commit-graph, since it is not compatible with the shallow view of the repository. That's handled by [829a321](https://github.com/git/git/commit/829a321569d8e8f2c582aef9f0c990df976ab842) (`commit-graph`: close_commit_graph before shallow walk, 2018-08-20, Git v2.19.2).
>   That commit literally closes and frees our `repo->objects->commit_graph struct`.
>
> That creates an interesting problem for commits that have *already* been
>   parsed using the commit graph.
>   Their `commit->object.parsed` flag is set, their `commit->graph_pos` is set, but their `commit->maybe_tree` may still be `NULL`.
>   When somebody later calls `repo_get_commit_tree()`, we see that we haven't loaded the tree oid yet and try to get it from the commit graph.
>   But since it has been freed, we segfault!
>
> So the root of the issue is a data dependency between the commit's
>   lazy-load of the tree oid and the fact that the commit graph can go
>   away mid-process.

Answer (score 8):

When working with git-svn:

git grafts are very useful to import a Git tree into a Subversion repository.

E.g. I created a local Git repository as a start. After working on it several days, creating lots of commits, I had to publish it into the central Subversion repository and I didn't want to lose the history.

I found the following How-to article: 
http://eikke.com/importing-a-git-tree-into-a-subversion-repository/