# How to merge two branches without a common ancestor?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I have started using Git in the middle of my project, where the first two commits are just some initial settings (.gitignore and .gitattributes), and the third commit **M2** adds the content of the SVN trunk:

```
I1 -- I2 -- M2 -- N -- .. -- Z
```

I have imported the SVN history in a branch named **svn**, where **M1** is the SVN trunk (with the same content as **M2**, except .gitignore and .gitattributes):

```
A -- B -- ... -- K -- L -- M1
```

**Q:** What is the best approach in merging both branches?

I could merge **M1** and **M2** into **M3**, and then rebase, but I don't know how to delete the **I1** and **I2** commits and if I can safely remove the **M3** commit (I have found some advices to preserve the merge commits, but in this case **M3** it's not necessary anymore).

```
A -- B -- ... -- K -- L -- M1
                             \
                              M3 -- N' -- .. -- Z'
                             /
               I1 -- I2 -- M2 -- N -- .. -- Z
```

Another way would be to cherry-pick the **N** .. **Z** commits into **svn** branch by hand, but I would like to avoid this approach.

The most elegant solution would be to rebase the changes introduced by **N** .. **Z** commits on top of **svn** branch, but I didn't found yet the required syntax for two branches without a common ancestor.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: *I've only used "graft points" myself once in a toy repository. But it is an obscure feature which you may not have heard of, and which _may_ be helpful in your situation.*

You could use "graft points" to fake the ancestry information. See, e.g., [What are .git/info/grafts for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161928/what-are-git-info-grafts-for) or proceed immediately to [the git wiki entry on graft points](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/GraftPoint).

In essence, you would create a file `.git/info/grafts` that tricks git into thinking that commit **M1** is an ancestor of commit **M2**:

```
$ cat .git/info/grafts
<your M2 commit hash> <your M1 commit hash>
```

Subsequently, it would look like **M2** was an empty commit that just merged **I2** and **M1** into a common tree.

***The major downside***: the graft point is not committed; therefore, it is not checked out, but needs to be added to each local working copy of the repository manually.

---

---

***Update:*** *use [**`git replace --graft`**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace) instead.*

Graft points, as described above, have been superseded.  Run

```
git replace --graft <your M2 commit hash> <your M1 commit hash>
```

to create the graft.  This is stored in `.git/refs/replace/`.  Although git does not fetch, or push, these refs by default, they can be synchronized between repositories using:

```
git push origin 'refs/replace/*'
git fetch origin 'refs/replace/*:refs/replace/*'
```

([StackOverflow: How to push 'refs/replace' without pushing any other refs in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20072413/1172714))

Comment: You can use "`git filter-branch`" to **rewrite history** according to grafts, turning grafted parentage into real parentage.  But that rewrites history.

Comment: @Jakub: would you give an example of using filter-branch with grafts (as an answer in order to be able to upvote) ? I'm ok with rewriting history.

Comment: IIRC, in the grafts file you need to mention the the current commit and _all_ of its parents. So on one line there would be the hashes of M2, M1 and I2 - unless you want to get rid of commits I1 and I2. By having only M2 and M1 in the grafts line, it'll look like M2 committed the contents of I1 and I2 on top of M1.

Comment: It's worth noting that grafts have been superseded by "git replace" as a way to fake a common ancestor.

Comment: @stsquad and `git replace` actually *is* committed to repository. Or at least can be.

Answer (score 6):

> The most elegant solution would be to rebase the changes introduced by N .. Z commits on top of svn branch, but I didn't found yet the required syntax for two branches without a common ancestor.

Try to first cherry-pick I1 and I2 onto M1, and after that use the command `git rebase --onto M1' M2 Z` (where M1' is the M1-I1-I2 branch). I'm not sure whether rebase --onto works when there are no common ancestors, but if it doesn't, there is the possibility of using patches. Use the `git format-patch` to generate the patches of M2..Z and then `git am` to apply them on top of M1. [Here are some experience reports](http://blog.orfjackal.net/search/label/git) on using it in converting old SVN and CVS repositories.

Answer (score 5):

I'd do the following:

```
git checkout M1
git cherry-pick I1
git cherry-pick I2
```

That adds .gitignore and .gitattributes to your branch containing the nicer history.

And then just set the new commits on top of that one:

```
git filter-branch --parent-filter 'if $GIT_COMMIT = $hash_of_N; then printf -- '-p
$hash_of_cherrypicked_I2\n'; else cat; fi'
```

The downside of this is you rewrite history.

So an alternative approach is to create a script similar to [the one for the Linux kernel](http://lkml.org/lkml/2006/4/6/176)
and put that in your repository.