# It is possible to merge/rebase non direct relationship branches?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-branch

As a integration test I would like to join several branches before merging them with my master.

All of them diverged from the master and make it's own way. It is a correct merging different branches with no direct-relationship (e.g. parent/child)??

Is there any good practise for rejoining branches??

Thanks in advance,
Raul.

Answer (score 1):

If those branches come all from master, they do have a common ancestor

```
     y--y--y
    /
x--o--x--x--x--x--x--x
          \
           z--z--z
```

('o' being the common ancestor here)
In that case, a merge in an integration branch is a good approach (rebasing such long-lived branch would involve rewriting too much public history)

If the branches are truly separate, then a **git grafts points** could in theory allow for a common history: see  [How to merge two branches without a common ancestor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488753/how-to-merge-two-branches-without-a-common-ancestor).
But that is not ideal, since the graft point is not committed.
A `filter-branch` might make the modification permanent, but that rewrite history.

Comment: I'd say this even more strongly: rejoining branches which have diverged from a common ancestor is not just good practice; it's *precisely* the purpose of `git-merge`.

Answer (score 0):

If those branches come all from master, they do have a common ancestor.

---

But answering your question (but not your problem), it is possible to merge two histories without common ancestor, for example two different projects, using for example 'subtree' merge strategy of `git merge`.

To rebase one branch on top of the other that doesn't have common ancestor, you would need to use `--root` option to `git rebase`.