# git: rebase with bases untracked in git

Tags: git

I'm improving some legacy codes, and I use git to handle versions. And I found another branch of the SAME legacy codes, so I want to merge it to my codes. The question is:
the initial commits of these two versions are different, so I can't simply rebase in git.

```
NOW:
(origin) -- (untracked modifications) -- my tracked improvements 
         \- (other untracked modifications) --some other tracked improvements 
NEEDED:
(origin) -- some other tracked improvements -- my tracked improvements
```

As in the graph, the two branches are in 2 individual repositories.

I think what I need maybe just import all the changed into another new repository, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 2 very similar repos, you could use graft points in order to make a commit of one repo the parent of the other repo, allowing you to rebase after that.
You have an example with "[How to merge two branches without a common ancestor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488753/how-to-merge-two-branches-without-a-common-ancestor)", but you would need a `git filter-branch` to make what is a *local* modification (graft point) permanent.

Another more classic solution would be to use **[subtree merging](http://progit.org/book/ch6-7.html)** (also presented in the [Pro Git book](http://progit.org/book/ch6-7.html)).

The blog post "[Having Fun with Git Subtree](http://h2ik.co/2011/03/having-fun-with-git-subtree/)" gives you an example of such a merge between two repo.

Comment: @Haocheng: excellent. Can you post as an answer the solution you choosed (graft or subtree merge?) and the commands you typed to achieve what you wanted?