# Concatenate the history of two Git repositories?

Tags: git, merge, repository, history, commit

I have an old Git repo, call it `app`. Then, after a year, I wanted to rebuild the app from scratch, so I made a new repo, call it `app-2`.

Now, I realize I should've just made a new branch or something, instead of a new repo, because I want to move the history of `app-2` on top of `app` and then get rid of `app-2` so that `app` now has all the history of `app` + `app-2`.

Is this possible to do?

UPDATE:

I tried "reseting" the `app` repo by removing all the files in `app` (except for the `.git` directory) and making a commit. Then:

```
cd ~/Projects/app-2
git format-patch --stdout --root master > ../app/app-2-patches.txt
cd ../app
git am app-2-patches.txt
```

But, I got conflicts in places where I had branches in `app-2`.

Is it possible to apply the commits from `app-2` while keeping the branch structure of the history of `app-2`?

Comment: Is there a reason you need them to be in the same repo? And if so, is there a reason they have to be in the same branch? Why not just have a separate branch to store the history of the old version, and then just make your current new app be the master branch as-is?

Answer (score 1):

You can use git's graft points for this. First pull the history of `app` into `app-2` from a remote, then follow the instructions e.g. in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1491057/176922).

Comment: Specifically: You can use `git filter-branch` to turn a grafted history into "real" history, then get rid of the graft point. Keep in mind that this will change all your commit ids!

Answer (score 0):

Step one is get the two apps in one repo; step two is merge them in some sensible way.

For step one I'd say push all of the repository branches in app-2 to branches in the app repository:

```
$ cd /path/to/app-2
$ git remote add app-repo /path/to/app
$ git push app-repo master:app-2-master     # master in app-2 goes to app-2-master in app repo
# repeat for other branches in app-2
```

Now over in the app repository you have all its branches and all the app-2 branches.  Let's say you (want to) consider app-2 as derived from app.  Then you rebase all of app-2 on app with:

```
$ cd /path/to/app
$ git checkout app-2-master
$ git rebase master
```

this might involve lots of work to resolve conflicts but git will be doing loads of work for you too.

Comment: nit: `git add remote` should be `git remote add`