# How do I append one git history to another?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree

I have a repository that contains the code for an old version of a website that is no longer being used on `master`. The site was completely redesigned in a new repository, and the code and history from that repository was copied over into a branch in the repo of the old site, let's call it `new_site`. I can't merge `new_site` into `master`, since the histories are entirely different.

I've investigated both submodules and subtree merges a bit, but both seem to only be relevant when you're trying to keep code from one project contained in a subdirectory of another project, not when you want to stick two working trees on top of each other.

At this point, I would like to have the old code remain where it is, and just append `new_site` on top of the current HEAD. Any idea how I can accomplish this, or alternate suggestions for cleaning up this mess without blowing away the old code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The general idea is:

- explained in "[How to combine two separate unrelated Git repositories into one with single history timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9781995/6309)" (fetch + cherry-picking)
- implemented in "[Concatenate the history of two Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10355123/6309)"

  ```
  git clone <git repository B url>
  cd <git repository B directory>
  git remote add repo-A-branch <git repository A directory>
  git fetch repo-A-branch master
  git remote rm repo-A-branch
  ```

Once you have imported the right branch from A, you can  use **[graft point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1491057/6309)**, and then `git filter-branch` to turn a grafted history into "real" history, to get rid of the graft point.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this script a while ago, which handles a common case for this (append a repository's history to another repository in a subdirectory):

https://github.com/multi-io/utils/blob/master/git-append-repo

Comment: Interesting script, more detailed than my answer. +1