# Git: Create a Framework out of a Project, and let the project base on the Framework

Tags: git

I created a Project (https://github.com/twaldecker/vim-cheat-sheet) and now I realized that I like the style of the cheatsheet and want to create a template out of it.

What I did is:

```
git clone cheatsheet-vim cheatsheet-template
cd cheatsheet-template
# remove vim specific content, some additions
cd ../cheatsheet-vim #go back to vim project
git checkout -b testbranch #create a new branch
git remote add template ../cheatsheet-template
git fetch template
git merge template/master #now I got the template project as branch in the base project
```

The question now is how to let the vim-cheatsheet project base on the template created out of the project itself.

What I want to have:

- have the template project which I can change
- have the cheatsheet-vim project where I can pull the canges from the template

Comment: I know the source is not very large and it would be easy to just recreate the vim-cheatsheet and copy the relevant sources back but I would like to learn the real git way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, since you have two branches without a common ancestor, you can try and `rebase --onto` your current master on top of template/master (with 'template' being the name of your remote referring the template repo).

That is one of the solutions presented in "[How to merge two branches without a common ancestor?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4718411/6309)".

That way, the two branches will have a common history, and you will be able to do so `git pull --rebase` when your template changes (to rebase again your current work on top of the modified fetched template)

---

The [OP Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/605586/thomas) tool another approach and [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861456/git-create-a-framework-out-of-a-project-and-let-the-project-base-on-the-framew/13862201#comment19314966_13862201):

> I ended up creating a new Project and copy the source.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think it doesn't answer my question. The template is based of the vim-cheatsheet and then removed the content. Now I want the vim-cheatsheet base on the template.

Comment: @Thomas "I want the vim-cheatsheet base on the template": that is what the `rebase --onto` would do: reapply what you have done  in vim-cheatsheet on top of (ie "based on") the template.

Comment: I ended up creating a new Project and copy the source.

Comment: @Thomas ok, I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.