# How to push 'refs/replace' without pushing any other refs in git?

Tags: git

I have done a replacement of one commit with another in this way:

```
* HEAD
|
...
|
* ==> *  `git replace left_commit right_commit`
|     |
*-----/
|
...
```

This replacement is placed in .git/refs/replace folder, so I wonder - how can I push this refs to the remote end?

Comment: Interesting question. I found this http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/17/replace.html and tried to follow it on a sample project. In the end I tried to `git push -f` but in my remote repository I did not see the replacing commit (I just reword a commit on history). Can you confirm that `git push -f` does not push to upstream the replacing?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Found the answer in [mailing-list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/187800):

```
git push origin 'refs/replace/*'
git fetch origin 'refs/replace/*:refs/replace/*'
```

Only explicit pushing and fetching do work right now in git.