# Squash frequent merge history from main branch into one

Tags: git, git-merge, git-squash

For example, I just merged master branch to my feature branch. Then someone pushed new stuff on master. So I merged again to keep up. And then someone pushed again... I merge again. How do I squash the previous merges so that two merge actions is combined to one?

How can I turn this:

```
o---o---A---B---C---D---E
         \       \   \   \
          F---G---H---I---J
```

into this:

```
o---o---A---B---C---D---E
         \               \
          F---G-----------J'
```

where J and J' contain exactly the same codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method prevents the need to re-resolve merge-conflicts by re-playing the previously-resolved changes into the merge commit.

```
git checkout feature
git diff master > feature.patch
git reset --hard G
git branch --move trimmed_feature
git checkout -b feature master
git merge --strategy ours trimmed_feature --no-edit
git apply feature.patch --index
git commit --amend --message "Merge branch 'master' into feature"
git branch -D trimmed_feature
```

We first remove the old merges to create a trimmed feature branch, then create a clean feature branch from master, merge in our trimmed feature branch using `git merge --strategy ours` to ignore the changes, then re-apply the previously-resolved changes from the patch.

Comment: Thanks, I learned a lot about git today. But there is still a small problem, although the result of merge action in git is symmetric, a merged commit still distinguish its "first parent" and "second parent". The way you give inverted the two parents. I think the main difficulty comes from that git doesn't have "git merge --strategy theirs".

Comment: A previous version of this answer talked about "theirs" but I removed it for brevity. About the parent order, I don't think it has any practical effect on anything so I won't add it here, but if you really want to, [you can swap it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36528357/1225617).

Answer (score 1):

If you have only made merge commits to feature since `G` as in your diagram, you can reset your branch back to that commit (using `--hard` to also reset your working copy files), and then redo the merge:

```
git checkout feature
git reset --hard G
git merge master
```

You can also use `git rebase master` instead of `git merge master` so that your branch contains only commits `F'` and `G'`, branching from `E` on master.

Comment: Thanks. But in my case, I have resolved a lot of conflicts in "H" and "I", so I don't want to do it again. I really want some kind of squash that can reuse my conflict resolving.