# How to concatenate two git histories?

Tags: git, repository, history

I have two git repositories that are tangentially related. Namely, content of one was a predecessor of the other. I would like to somehow prepend the full history of depository A to the depository B, so that tip of A would be a parent of the very first changeset of repository B? Histories in both are pretty linear.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try using the graft file (`.git/info/grafts`) where you could overwrite the parenthood of a commit (like the first of `projectB` having for parent the latest of `projectA`)

See also "[What are .git/info/grafts for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161928/what-are-git-info-grafts-for)" and "[How to prepend the past to a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147097/how-to-prepend-the-past-to-a-git-repository)" for more on this manipulation.

---

[skalee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/304175/skalee) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219713/how-to-concatenate-two-git-histories/3219820#comment19243222_3219820) about the article "[Git: Grafting repositories](http://ben.straubnet.net/post/939181602/git-grafting-repositories)" (from SO user **[Ben Straub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1319/ben-straub)**) for a concrete example.

> Now what we want to do is change the first commit in the “`nuevo`” repo (“`New commit #1`”) so that its parent is the last commit in the “old” repo (“Old #3”). Time for some voodoo:

```
git fetch ../old master:ancient_history
```

> Git lets you fetch from any other git repository, whether this repo is related to it or not! Brilliant! This leaves us with this:

[image]

> Note how we renamed the old master branch to ancient_history. If we hadn’t, git would have tried to merge the two, and probably given up in disgust.
>
> Now we still have a problem.
>   The two trees aren’t connected, and in fact a git pull won’t even get the ancient_history branch at all. We need a way to make a connection between the two.
>
> Git has a facility called a graft, which basically fakes up a parent link between two commits.
>   To make one, just insert a line into the **`.git/info/grafts`** file in this format:

```
[ref] [parent]
```

> Both of these need to be the full hash of the commits in question. So let’s find them:

```
$ git rev-list master | tail -n 1
d7737bffdad86dc05bbade271a9c16f8f912d3c6

$ git rev-parse ancient_history
463d0401a3f34bd381c456c6166e514564289ab2

$ echo d7737bffdad86dc05bbade271a9c16f8f912d3c6 \
       463d0401a3f34bd381c456c6166e514564289ab2 \
       > .git/info/grafts
```

(in one line, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219713/how-to-concatenate-two-git-histories/3219820?noredirect=1#comment70834980_3219820) by [ssokolow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/435253/ssokolow))

```
echo $(git rev-list master | tail -n 1) $(git rev-parse ancient_history) > .git/info/grafts
```

There. Now our history looks like this:

[image]

> Cloning this repo results in this:

[image]

> Woops. It turns out that grafts only take effect for the local repository. We can fix this with judicious application of **[`git fast-import`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fast-import)**:

```
$ git fast-export --all > ../export

$ mkdir ../nuevo-complete

$ cd ../nuevo-complete

$ git init

$ git fast-import < ../export
git-fast-import statistics: [...]
```

(in one line, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219713/how-to-concatenate-two-git-histories/3219820?noredirect=1#comment70836425_3219820) by [ssokolow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/435253/ssokolow))

```
git filter-branch $(git rev-parse ancient_history)..HEAD
```

> This effectively converts our “fake” history link into a real one.
>   All the engineers will have to re-clone from this new repository, since the hashes will all be different, but that’s a small price to pay for no downtime and a complete history.

[image]

As [Qix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/510036/qix) comments [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219713/how-to-concatenate-two-git-histories/3219820?noredirect=1#comment50801357_3219820):

> `fast-import` appears to just import the git information, but doesn't check anything out.
>   `git init` originally puts you on master, so **you need a `git reset --hard HEAD` to actually check the files out after you `fast-import`**.

Comment: Worked just fine for me, thanks VonC, didn't think it would be that simple.

Comment: Then you can rewrite history using `git filter-branch` to make what graft brought permanent... but this rewrites history.

Comment: Short and neat article which really helped me to understand what grafts are and step-by-step how to join those histories: http://ben.straubnet.net/post/939181602/git-grafting-repositories

Comment: @skalee good article. I have included the main commands in the answer.

Comment: Shoot, that was easy. Might want to mention, too, that a `git reset --hard HEAD` needs to happen as the `fast-import` doesn't check out the head of master for you (so instantly `git status` shows that you deleted everything).

Comment: @Qix do you mean a reset --hard just at the end after the fast-import step?

Comment: @VonC correct. `fast-import` appears to just import the git information, but doesn't check anything out. `git init` originally puts you on master, so you need a `git reset --hard HEAD` to actually check the files out after you fast-import.

Comment: @Qix Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: You might want to suggest people use this command to minimize the chance of copy-paste errors: `echo $(git rev-list master | tail -n 1) $(git rev-parse ancient_history) > .git/info/grafts`

Comment: @ssokolow Thank you. I have included your suggestion in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I also just finished checking whether there was a more elegant alternative to using `fast-export` and `fast-import` and the `filter-branch` manpage actually has an example for just this situation. Here's the adjusted version I ran and then tested the output of: `git filter-branch $(git rev-parse ancient_history)..HEAD`. (Reminders: If you have uncommitted changes, you'll need to run `git stash` before and `git stash pop` after. If this isn't your first time running `filter-branch`, you may need to add `-f` to overwrite an old refs backup.)

Comment: @ssokolow nice: you can edit the answer to include that alternative version.

Comment: Done. I also fixed a typo where you accidentally cut off the "N" in "Now" at the beginning of a quote.