# Merging two repos with gitolite

Tags: git, gitolite

I need to merge two repos using Gitolite, I recall seeing some instructions somewhere but can't find them.

Should the combining (merging) be done in Gitolite or on another machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gitolite is only an [authorization layer](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html).
It is doing nothing more than allowing or denying `git pull/push/clone` commands, based on authentication and VREFs (update hooks).

You can merge two repo locally with git commands (see "[How do you merge two git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)"), and then push to your Gitolite server.

Gitolite will be used only to declare, if needed, a third repo to get the result of the merge (unless you are directly modifying one of the two repo with the other)

Comment: Note to self: one way to merge (at least concatenate) two repo histories: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219713/how-to-concatenate-two-git-histories/3219820#3219820