# Concatenate CVS and Git repos into one Git repo

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge, cvs

This is a multiphase question. I am looking for
the current state of the art to completing it
and linking separate resources doing disjoined
parts.

Short story of what I need:

1. convert a full-history CVS repo into git as a base
2. concatenate an existing git repo for that same project on top of the above
3. publish the merged repo on github
4. merge in forks from the 2nd step

My issue is as follows (a longer story):

- I have a relatively large original CVS repo, let's call it `O_cvs`
  with some branches, tags, etc., lots of history for over 10 years.
- At some point a copy (one of) of a checkout of that repo `O_cvs` was made
  and pushed into a Git repo as a starting point, let's call it `O_git`. There
  were no further commits to `O_cvs`; nor further development is planned in `O_cvs` after migration.
- `O_git` had a number of features added and projects forked, some
  are merged via pull requests and some aren't, say `F1_git`, `F2_git`, etc.

Thus, my plan with question where appropriate:

1. I care for the history and contributors and tags in `O_cvs` that I would
   like to preserve as a base.
   As a result I would like to produce a repo, let's call it `G_git` (local?) from `O_cvs`.
   What's the current recommended tool to do that
   for me? I researched here and elsewhere and found different suggestions
   posted over the years featured, e.g., in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869710), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881158), [and here](https://www.isostech.com/blogs/software-development/journey-cvs-git/):

   - [`git-cvsimport`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcvs-migration)
   - [`cvs2git` extension of `svn2git`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/885148/5896674)
   - [CVS2GIT](https://github.com/tikalk/tikal-alm-tools/tree/master/scm-tools/scm-migration/manual/CVS2GIT) wrapper for `cvs2git` from Tikal
   - ["`crap`"](https://github.com/rcls/crap) -- Cvs Remote Access Program
   - [More tools from kernel.org](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Interfaces,_frontends,_and_tools#CVS)
2. I then plan to publish `G_git` on GitHub (only question here should this be the order), as `G`.
3. I care for the `O_git` and its forks, hosted elsewhere, so I'd pull that in.
4. I want to concatenate the histories of `G_git` + `O_git`, and push them to GitHub, into the combined repo `G`.
   From my research "grafting" and fast import seem the way to go here.

   - so would I [graft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219713) `O_git` onto `G_git` on GitHub (should grafting be done before pushing `G_git` to GitHub?)
5. I will work on pull requests to `O_git` from `F1_git`, `F2_git`, etc. (may take awhile, but `G` needs to be out sooner) to integrate them into `G` (will there be a problem? do I have to go through the intermediate steps to `O_git`, and then via an additional remote to `G`?)

Recommendations on the current tools and the sequence above and associated pitfalls are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The best recommended solution (I'm well experienced in that issue) is to keep the CVS repo as read-only repository and merge the latest revision to the git repository without history. You'll benefit from it a lot for the long run!

About the tool for the migration, try (my tool): https://github.com/tikalk/tikal-alm-tools

Comment: your tool under the hood uses `cvs2git` -- why that choice specifically? I also care for the history and contributors especially in `O_cvs`.

Comment: forgot to mention the CVS repo isn't planned to be used for development in the future after migration completes. I will edit the question to that effect.

Comment: Well, I wrote it long ago so I don't recall why but it worked for me for migrating several customers-projects