# Git merge two overlapping repositories

Tags: git

I have this configuration:

```
RepoA
  |-Dir1

RepoB
```

The problem is that RepoB is copied and modified Dir1. Is there a way how to merge RepoB into RepoA without loosing history on RepoB?

Comment: Is `Dir1` a git repository by itself? If not, how can `RepoB` be a copy of it? Did you copy `Dir1` and then `git init`ed it?

Comment: @Shahbaz Dir1 is not a git repository by itself. Yeah, it wasn't my brightest moment.

Comment: haha, well I don't know what to do now, but maybe you could take a look at "sub-modules" or something. I don't know them, but if you can turn Dir1 into a sub-module, then add `../../RepoB` as a remote to it, then fetch/merge, you'll get Dir1 updated. Then, you could try to see if it is possible to get Dir1 back as a directory rather than a sub-module. Note: test on a test repository first!!

Comment: Are you looking for something like [graft](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161928/what-are-git-info-grafts-for)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combining multiple git repositories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277029/combining-multiple-git-repositories)

Answer (score 0):

There definitely is a way to rescue the history in `RepoB`, which, if it is understood correctly, represents a version of `Dir1` under `RepoA`.

1. First, I would begin by rewriting the history of the development branch in `RepoB` so that all the files are renamed according to the pattern `* -> Dir1\*`.   That is to say, I would go to the earliest commit, perform a `git mv` of all the files into the subdirectory, and then rebase everything else. This is doable with `git rebase --interactive`. I would create a branch for this that does not exist in `RepoA`. Let's call that the `rescue` branch.
2. Next, I would point both `RepoA` and `RepoB` to a common ancestor. If `RepoA` has an upstream, then `RepoB`'s `.git/config` can be edited to point to that same upstream.
3. Then we push the `rescue` branch in `RepoB` into the upstream, and do a `git fetch` in `RepoA` to pick that up. `RepoA` now has the materials.
4. At this point, in `RepoA`, we can cherry pick the `rescue` branch commits into the development branch.

Concrete scenario, from scratch. In this session, we create a `repo-a` which is cloned from `upstream`. In `repo-a` we create a `dir1/file`. Then we create a new git repo `repo-b` as a copy of `dir1`. We do some hacking on `file`. Then we rewrite the history so that the file is moved to `dir/file` and the changes are replayed, and we do that in a branch called `rescue`. We establish `upstream` as the remote of `repo-b` and push `rescue` there. We then pull `rescue` into `repo-a`, rebase `rescue` on top of `master`, and then install `rescue` as `master`.

**Note:** The history rewriting in `rescue` was hacked using some manual commands. I first hard reset to the base commit, did a `git mv` to move the file to the subdirectory, and amended that root commit. Then I cherry picked the next commit after that. In reality, I would do a `git rebase --interactive <root-commit-sha>`, but that is difficult to show as a logged session.

```
~$ mkdir upstream
~$ mkdir repo-a
~$ cd upstream
~/upstream$ git init --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/kaz/upstream/
~/upstream$ cd ../repo-a
~/repo-a$ git clone ../upstream .
Cloning into '.'...
done.
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
~/repo-a$ mkdir dir1
~/repo-a$ cd dir1
~/repo-a/dir1$ cat > file
abc
def
~/repo-a/dir1$ git add file
~/repo-a/dir1$ git commit -m "file added"
[master (root-commit) 1b5cdf9] file added
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 dir1/file
~/repo-a/dir1$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 4, done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 252 bytes, done.
Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done.
To /home/kaz/repo-a/../upstream
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Okay, now here comes the silly part: someone makes a copy of `repo-a/dir1`, calling it `repo-b`, and initializes that as a Git repo, adding `file` under version control and committing:

```
~/repo-a/dir1$ cd ../..
~$ cp -a repo-a/dir1 repo-b
~$ cd repo-b
~/repo-b$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/kaz/repo-b/.git/
~/repo-b$ git add file
~/repo-b$ git commit -m "repob"
[master (root-commit) fe0c898] repob
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 file
```

Now, that same person starts working on `file`, adding material to it:

```
~/repo-b$ cat file
abc
def
~/repo-b$ cat >> file
ghi
~/repo-b$ git diff
diff --git a/file b/file
index 5f5521f..8edb37e 100644
--- a/file
+++ b/file
@@ -1,2 +1,3 @@
 abc
 def
+ghi
~/repo-b$ git commit -a -m "ghi"
[master 3e35a62] ghi
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

Now the person realizes, "Oh no, what am I doing! I want this change over in `repo-a`, under `dir1`!".

First step is to connect `repo-b` to `upstream`:

```
~/repo-b$ git remote add origin ../upstream
```

Now, stop working on `master`, and change over to a `rescue` branch which starts out identical to `master`:

```
~/repo-b$ git checkout -b rescue
Switched to a new branch 'rescue'
~/repo-b$ git log
commit 3e35a6216f8788cc7a58f7bb84a2dfaf8e47e720
Author: Kaz <kaz@stackoverflow.help.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 19 22:17:54 2014 -0800

    ghi

commit fe0c898b11124d0174e65b32fdcc956443446dcf
Author: Kaz <kaz@stackoverflow.help.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 19 22:17:25 2014 -0800

    repob
```

Now, rewrite the history of `rescue` so that the file is under `dir1`. First, reset to the root commit, and do the rename:

```
~/repo-b$ git reset --hard fe0c898b11124d0174e65b32fdcc956443446dcf
HEAD is now at fe0c898 repob
~/repo-b$ mkdir dir1
~/repo-b$ git mv file dir1
~/repo-b$ git commit -a --amend -m "repob"
[rescue e3a6c19] repob
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 dir1/file
```

Now, we cherry pick the change on top. The change nicely patches over `dir1/file`, following the rename:

```
~/repo-b$ git cherry-pick 3e35a6216f8788cc7a58f7bb84a2dfaf8e47e720
[rescue 7f21bf5] ghi
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
~/repo-b$ ls
dir1
~/repo-b$ cat dir1/file 
abc
def
ghi
```

Okay, now we push the rescue package to `../upstream`:

```
~/repo-b$ git push origin rescue
Counting objects: 8, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 507 bytes, done.
Total 8 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (8/8), done.
To ../upstream
 * [new branch]      rescue -> rescue
```

Off to `repo-a` once again. There we do a `git fetch` to bring in the `rescue` branch and its objects:

```
~/repo-b$ cd ..
~$ cd repo-a
~/repo-a$ git fetch
remote: Counting objects: 8, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 8 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (8/8), done.
From /home/kaz/repo-a/../upstream
 * [new branch]      rescue     -> origin/rescue
```

From here on in, it is Git 101 material. We rebase the `rescue` branch on top of `master`.

```
~/repo-a$ git checkout rescue
Branch rescue set up to track remote branch rescue from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'rescue'
~/repo-a$ git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: ghi
~/repo-a$ ls
dir1
~/repo-a$ cat dir1/file 
abc
def
ghi
~/repo-a$ # YAY!
```

Then we switch back to `master`, and fast-forward it to `rescue`:

```
~/repo-a$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
~/repo-a$ git reset --hard rescue
HEAD is now at 2546207 ghi
~/repo-a$ cat dir1/file 
abc
def
ghi
```

Done.