# Pruning old Git commits without rebasing

Tags: git, garbage-collection, git-rewrite-history

Suppose I have a Git repository with huge trees (~60 GiB) and some history, where old versions contain many deleted files.

I now want to **prune old history**, but **without** `rebase`ing all the commits after the prune point, because that would take several hours for each commit.

- Can I just delete the first commit object to remove, and hope for `git gc` to delete all (now unreferenced) older ones? Or will this cause panic because of missing objects?
- Can I use `git replace` to replace the first commit I want to remove with a dummy commit and *then* call `git gc`?
- Is there some other method to remove my old commits in-place?

Comment: I think any kind of history rewriting will have to involve rewriting everything after the prune point anyways, unless each commit's sha ID isn't actually based off the data of its parent. You might be able to do with more efficiently with `git filter-branch` or the BFG Repo Cleaner.

Comment: Each commit's SHA-1 ID *is* based on the data of its parent commits by design. You have to rebase: each commit from your prune point will need to have a completely new ID because it is based on different earlier commit IDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> without rebasing all the commits after the prune point, because that would take several hours for each commit.

### After Git 2.18 (Q2 2018)

Since Git 2.18, [`graft` has been superseded by git `ref/replace/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50517809/6309)): see "[What are `.git/info/grafts` for?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50517809/6309)".

As noted by in the comments, you would use instead
[`git replace --convert-graft-file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace#Documentation/git-replace.txt---convert-graft-file) :

> Creates graft commits for all entries in `$GIT_DIR/info/grafts` and deletes that file upon success.
> The purpose is to help users with transitioning off of the now-deprecated graft file.

So after `git rev-parse HEAD~100 > .git/info/grafts`.

And [`git filter-branch` or BFG are obsolete after Git 2.22](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309)

Install [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo#how-do-i-install-it=) and [use `git filter-repo --force`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/933475ecf1b58b452faa3f4f39d7da6d7d1d404d/Documentation/git-filter-repo.txt#L987-L994=)

---

### Before Git 2.18 (Q2 2018):

That is what [graft point](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GraftPoint) is for (better in that particular case than [`git replace`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace), as I [detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6802005/6309))

The file `.git/info/grafts` with only one line with a commit id, says that the commit doesn't have a parent.
To keep the last 100 commits, using [`git rev-parse`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse):

```
 git rev-parse HEAD~100 > .git/info/grafts
```

Then:

```
 git filter-branch -- --all
```

Finally:

```
rm -Rf .git/refs/original
```

Then you can prune the rest:

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
git repack -Ad      # kills in-pack garbage
git prune           # kills loose garbage
```

Comment: But grafts don't get pushed/pulled, right? It sounds great not to have to create an empty replacement commit. I'm guessing there is no way to make it so that replaces can be transferred using push/pull...

Comment: @cfstras no, grafts are purely local. Hence the need for the `git filter-branch`, to integrate their modification into the repo history. Once that is done, you can push the changed history. (a `push --force`, since the history has been rewritten, so make sure you are the only one working on that repo, or make sure your colleagues are aware of that change)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I'm guessing `git filter-branch` in this case will only reprocess the commit objects (changing the parent SHA), and will thus be almost instantaneous to run?

Comment: @cfstras yes, very quick (not "instantaneous" though, unless your history is quite small)

Comment: Wonderful! I'm not quite sure what my use-case for this question was when I asked it 3 years ago, but it's satisfying to see it answered :)

Comment: "fatal: empty ident name (for <>) not allowed" ... :(

Comment: @user1133275 What version of Git are you using?

Comment: @VonC git version 2.17.1 (Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS) this comment specifically; https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/af25e94d4dcfb9608846242fabdd4e6014e5c9f0

Comment: git version 2.26 says that grafts is deprecated and will be removed. One is urged to turn grafts into a replace ref with `git replace --convert-graft-file`.

Comment: @KevinBuchs Thank you for the feedback. It is 2.18 actually.  I have edited the answer to update the commands.